# Creating an object of a custom class and assigning methods to it

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to create an object of class "weeknumber", which would have the following format: "2019-W05"

Additionally, I need to be able to use this object with +- operators. Similarly like "Date" variables behave in base R. For instance:

- "2019-W05" + 1 = "2019-W06"
- "2019-W01" - 1 = "2018-W52"
- "2019-W03" - "2019-W01" = 2

I managed to partially achieve my goal. This is what I got so far:

```
weeknum <- function(date){

    # Function that creates weeknumber object from a date

    weeknumber <- paste(isoyear(date), formatC(isoweek(date), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0"), sep = "-W")
    class(weeknumber) <- c("weeknumber", class(weeknumber))
    weeknumber
}

week2date <- function(weeknumber, weekday = 4) {

    # Wrapper around ISOweek2date function from the 'ISOweek' package

    ISOweek2date(paste(weeknumber, weekday, sep = "-"))
}

"+.weeknumber" <- function(x, ...) {

    # Creating a method for addition

    x <- week2date(x) + sum(...)*7

    weeknum(x)
}

"-.weeknumber" <- function(x, ...) {

    # Creating a method for subtraction

    x <- week2date(x) - sum(...)*7

    weeknum(x)
}
```

What works:

```
> x <- weeknum("2019-01-01")

> x
[1] "2019-W01"
attr(,"class")
[1] "weeknumber" "character" 

> x + 1
[1] "2019-W02"
attr(,"class")
[1] "weeknumber" "character" 

> x - 1
[1] "2018-W52"
attr(,"class")
[1] "weeknumber" "character"
```

Works as expected! The only annoying thing is that calling the variable also 
prints out the attributes. Any way to hide them in the default print out?

What doesn't work:

```
> 1 + x
 Error: all(is.na(weekdate) | stringr::str_detect(weekdate, kPattern)) is not TRUE 

> y <- weeknum("2019-03-01")
> y - x
 Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

Any help appreciated!

**Edit:**

Figured out a solution how to make 1 + x (where x is a weeknumber) work. Not very elegant but does the job.

```
"+.weeknumber" <- function(...) {

    # Creating a method for addition

    vector <- c(...)

    week_index   <- which(unlist(lapply(list(...), function(x) class(x)[1]))=="weeknumber")
    week         <- vector[week_index]
    other_values <- sum(as.numeric(c(...)[-week_index]))

    x <- week2date(week) + other_values*7

    weeknum(x)

}

> x <- weeknum("2019-01-01")
> x
[1] "2019-W01"

> 5 + x + 1 + 2 - 1
[1] "2019-W08"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part: Define a custom `print`-method for your class:

```
print.weeknumber <- function(x,...) 
  {
  attributes(x) <- NULL
  print(x)
  }
```